# CSS I can hide an image but i can't show it back

Tags: css, block, display

i am learning CSS (*but i know some stuff*).
I am working on a demo webpage that i want to create with css to have a layout that i want.
Concept:
I have a container DIV which also has a top-div, left-div and content-div inside.
At first, with the help of media queries i make a layout for 3 different devices:

```
@media all and (min-width: 960px)
@media all and (min-width: 600px)
@media all and (min-width: 340px) and (max-width 599px)
```

So at the lowest `@media` i make the top bar position fixed to be always at the top, else it is not fixed its relative and it has some `margin`

The proble is i've got an icon a menu-bar icon that you see in mobile websites, i create an image tag within top-div and in css i have `display: none;`, `width: 6%;`, `height: 10%;` if it will work it will be awesome. But when inside the 3rd `@media` i type `div#container div#top-div img#menu_bar_icon{ display: block; }` it doesn't work!
I tried the opposite to have the default `display` at first (*just removed the `display: none` from the img*) and within the `@media` i type `div#container div#top-div img#menu_bar_icon{ display: none; }` and it WORKS....

I don't know why this is happening, please help me 
Thank you!

Comment: Just show your raw code (simplified to show only your issue)

Comment: try `display:block !important;` once, I am not sure it would work.

Comment: @viewsinhggits Thank you so MUCH! It worked just fine.